# Accessing attributes from dynamically created sibling elements

Tags: xslt-2.0

Learning XSLT!

I have an XML source tree fragment that looks like this:

Using Saxon and XSLT 2.0 to transform...

```
   <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <Chapter revision="B" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Content Ref="X123">
            <Ref name="INT1"/>
            <Ref name="INT2"/>
            <Ref name="INT3"/>
            <Ref name="INT4"/>
            <Ref name="INT5"/>
        </Content>
        <Data>
            <Reference name="INT1" Function="CONDUCTOR"></Reference>
            <Reference name="INT2" Function="SIGNAL"></Reference>
            <Reference name="INT3" Function="MIXED"></Reference>
            <Reference name="INT4" Function="PLANE"></Reference>
            <Reference name="INT5" Function="CORE"></Reference>
        </Data>
    </Chapter>
```

I want it to produce this:

```
<Chapter>
   <Content>
      <Ref id="INT1" Function="CONDUCTOR">INT1</Ref>
      <Ref id="INT2" Function="SIGNAL">INT2</Ref>
      <Ref id="INT3" Function="MIXED">INT3</Ref>
      <Ref id="INT4" Function="PLANE">INT4</Ref>
      <Ref id="INT5" Function="CORE">INT5</Ref>
   </Content>
</Chapter>
```

Here's my template fragment:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Chapter"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Chapter">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Content">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Ref"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Ref">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">

        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="Function">
            <xsl:value-of select="/Chapter/Data/Reference[@name=/Chapter/Data/Reference/@name]/@Function"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But the template above produces this: 
It is obviously picking up the values from every node

```
 <Chapter>
       <Content>
          <Ref id="INT1" Function="CONDUCTOR SIGNAL MIXED PLANE CORE">INT1</Ref>
          <Ref id="INT2" Function="CONDUCTOR SIGNAL MIXED PLANE CORE">INT2</Ref>
          <Ref id="INT3" Function="CONDUCTOR SIGNAL MIXED PLANE CORE">INT3</Ref>
          <Ref id="INT4" Function="CONDUCTOR SIGNAL MIXED PLANE CORE">INT4</Ref>
          <Ref id="INT5" Function="CONDUCTOR SIGNAL MIXED PLANE CORE">INT5</Ref>
       </Content>
    </Chapter>
```

What do I need to supply as a predicate value to step through the attribute values?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `/Chapter/Data/Reference[@name=/Chapter/Data/Reference/@name]/@Function` to `/Chapter/Data/Reference[@name=current()/@name]/@Function`, then learn about keys and define `<xsl:key name="ref" match="Data/Reference" use="@name"/>` and use `key('ref', @name)/@Function` instead to improve performance and readability.

In general you might want to learn about literal result elements and attribute value templates so that

```
<xsl:template match="Ref">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">

        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="Function">
            <xsl:value-of select="/Chapter/Data/Reference[@name=/Chapter/Data/Reference/@name]/@Function"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:template match="Ref">
    <Ref id="{@name}" Function="{key('ref', @name)/@Function}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </Ref>
</xsl:template>
```

and the complete code is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="Data/Reference" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Chapter">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Content">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Ref">
        <Ref id="{@name}" Function="{key('ref', @name)/@Function}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </Ref>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin, Many thanks for your solution. Works beautifully. And thank you for your other suggestions and for pointing me to additional areas of study. Very grateful for your time and trouble! Ralph

Comment: I used your suggestion of:/Chapter/Data/Reference[@name=current()/@name]/@Function

Comment: Martin, I used your suggestion of

/Chapter/Data/Reference[@name=current()/@name]/@Function

and it works fine. How would I get the Function associated with the previous name? I've tried using

[@name=preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name]

in the predicate but it returns nothing. Does current() have the same context as preceding-sibling?

Ralph B

Comment: Please ask a new question with the necessary details (XML sample, XSLT you have, output you get, output you want).